# Add a dependency to an Android Cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, cordova-plugins

I'm building a **Cordova Android plugin**. I want to use a 3rd party `View` inside an `Intent` that is **created by the plugin** (specifically [scissors](https://github.com/lyft/scissors)).
Normally (in non Cordova projects) I would go to my project's `build.gradle` file and add it like this:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.lyft:scissors:1.0.1' }
```

But it seems like the `build.gradle` file in my plugin's project wasn't meant to be touched?
What is the proper way to add a dependency to a plugin project, to support both builds via Cordova and builds via Android Studio?
Same question, but for a local project (not hosted on GitHub).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to use your own gradle file then link it on the `plugin.xml` like this

```
<framework src="relative/path/your.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />
```

You have to put that tag on the `plugin.xml`, so on plugin install it's read and cordova handles it (not sure how it works internally, but I suppose that it copies the values from your custom .gradle to the main build.gradle).

So you can't test it on your current project, you have to create a new project and add the plugin and see if it works

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. can you explain what do you mean by _use your own gradle file_ ?
is there a way to link the dependency to a git repository (such as in the link in the question)?

Comment: You create a new .gradle file with the text you posted on the question, then you link your .gradle file on your plugin.xml as I told you on my answer. Take a look into the crosswalk plugin

Comment: and how do I add it to Android Studio so that I can actually use it?

Comment: have you ever created a plugin before? read the plugin development guide http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html, try to create a basic plugin and once you get it working add the scissors

Comment: No, I haven't. It's a working plugin that I am editing. i'm pretty sure they used cordova create to generate all the files, and then just added a plugin.xml file, like this (old) tutorial suggests http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-how-to-write-a-phonegap-plugin-for-android/. this approach gives the advantage that I can test my plugin pretty easily. now, since my plugin is a cordova project itself, I can't just edit it's gradle files. I managed to work around this in the iOS version, but with android it seems more complicated. hope what i'm saying is making sense...

Comment: You have to put that tag I told you on the plugin.xml, so on plugin install it's  read and cordova handles it (not sure how it works internally, but I suppose that it copies the values in your custom .gradle to the main build.gradle). So you can't test it on your current project, you have to create a new project and add the plugin and see if it works

Comment: Thank. If you will edit the answer to contain the info in the comment, I will accept this as the answer.

Comment: What if I wanted to add to the application ? not to the plugin. tried adding in gradle file directly, but it removes when I do build.

Comment: @droidev when you add the plugin the dependency will be added to the app where you install the plugin

Comment: @jcesarmobile what if I am not using any plugins ? in my case I wanted to integrate facebook SDK, so I just wanted to add the gradle dependency and initialize in main activity.

Comment: @droidev create a plugin that just have the plugin.xml and the .gradle file (the framework tag should also work instead of the .gradle file)

Comment: @jcesarmobile is there any other better way ?

Comment: @droidev The other way is a hook that writes in the cordova .gradle file, but I don't think that's better

Comment: Will use this approach then.

Comment: @jcesarmobile `Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :k4l-video-trimmer.` when I add the module project in plugin and add that plugin in Ionic demo project

Comment: @KishoreJethava create a new question and provide the code you used

Comment: I didnt see plugin.xml in my root project folder. I only saw many plugin.xml under /plugins/cordova-xxx folder. Should I manually create the plugin.xml file?

Comment: The question is about adding dependencies to plugins, all plugins must have a plugin.xml. Looks like you are trying to do it to a regular cordova app without a plugin.

Answer (score 14):

The [Cordova Android plugins doc](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html#adding-dependency-libraries) (in "Adding Dependency Libraries") specify that you can add dependency libraries with the `<framework>` tag in your `plugin.xml`.

So for the scissors dependency you can use:

```
<platform name="android">
    <framework src="com.lyft:scissors:1.0.1" />
```

Comment: and after that? What do I need to do, so that I can use it in Android Studio?
running 'cordova prepare ios' seems not to be enough, Nor does build or clean.

Comment: Assuming you meant `cordova prepare android`, you need to create a Cordova app with a dependency to your plugin in order to test it. You can use `cordova plugin add <path/to/your/plugin>` from this test app to add the dependency before running `cordova prepare android`.

Comment: For some reason, when I tried this with my plugin, it seemed to occasionally cache these settings.  Making the above changes followed by:

     `cordova platform rm android`

     `cordova platform add android@5.1.1`

     `cordova plugin add myplugin`

Comment: It works for me. This answer must be checked as correct.

Comment: I didnt see plugin.xml in my root project folder. I only saw many plugin.xml under /plugins/cordova-xxx folder. Should I manually create the plugin.xml file?