# Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.!

Tags: android

I saw other questions about Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar and tried some solution, for example, project clean and rebuild, invalid caches and restart and the appcompat library version down, but nothing was working.

- gradle(i use Cordova, and it's not all codes from gradle)

  ```
  buildscript {
  repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  jcenter()
  maven {
      url 'https://dl.bintray.com/tonylee/maven/'
  }
  }

  // Switch the Android Gradle plugin version requirement depending on the
  // installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
  // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
  // and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
  dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
   }
  }


   dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
  debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
     releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
  // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
  provided 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
  compile 'com.fpang:adsync2:5.2.2'

  }
  ```
- Advertise.java

  ```
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  ```
- Toolbar in activity_main.xml

>

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/as2_sdk_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/app_name"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

-styles.xml

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

who knows about this errors please help me.

Comment: Please post your Error Stack from the logcat. And is this your full activity_main.xml? Because it does not have a container layout.

Comment: where is the toolbar in your xml

Comment: I don't know why all codes are not attached. I edit now.

Comment: post your gradle too..

Answer (score 0):

Please add dependencies `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'`

Comment: of coaurse, i added this code.     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'

Answer (score 0):

Try adding design library

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is only the problem with gradle dependency you can add both and check.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.0'
```

Comment: what is your compile sdk version ?

Comment: Please add this dependencies in your app gradle rather than adding in workspace gradle.

Comment: you need to add dependencies at project app level.

Comment: sorry i don't know what is the app gradle and workspace gradle. in Gradle Scripts, i have build.gradle(Module: CordovaLib), cordova.gradle(Module: CordovaLib), build.gradle(Module:android), gradle-wrapper.properties, proguard-rules.pro, setting.gradle, local.properties

Comment: what is your app name ?

Comment: my app name is papertalk and i use cordova (hybrid app framework)

Comment: Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314996/add-a-dependency-to-an-android-cordova-plugin

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    ***android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"***
```

All the material design element need to be removed as toolbar disallowed any material related element to be defined for API 19 and below.